# How to structure PHP MVC Models

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I want to know how to structure MVC models for example i have a User model which contains the basic CRUD operations and authentication functions. If i want to separate the functions so that one class represents Database interactions functions and another class to represent the buisness logic (login procedure etc) , how do i do that?

```
Class User{

    function getUser($id){

       //code

    }

    function create($data){

       //code

    }

    function update($id , $data){

       //code

    }

    function delete($id){

       //code

    }

    function authenticate($username , $password){

       //code

    }

    function createCookie(){

       //code

    }

}
```

Comment: May I know why would you want to re-invent the wheel instead of using some simple ORM like Idiorm which has these features?

Comment: @uglypointer I just want to understand how to seperate those functions rather than putting all of them in a single class

Comment: it's a bit hard to answer your question because it is "correct" -- those things should be separated. Just because you have 2 different responibilities: one is to deal with the `user` as a part of your application and another is persistence concern. I don't get your question `how do i do that?` You mean how to it technically? You write different classes that serve different needs. And since you are asking yourself such questions you can go further and stop treat MVC as application basis and think of it just as of GUI. Does every detail of your application really need to be known from GUI part?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following modifications

1. Create an abstract base model class with abstract CRUD functions and abstract variable which tells the table name the model will be working with.
2. For each of my table I would create a base table specific model inheriting my base model class and define table name and CRUD operations.
3. For defining all my extra functions I would make a model which may use the model(s) created in step 2 to do multiple operations

PS: This is not my original idea. This pattern is used by many PHP MVC frameworks to structure their code.